# Is there a way to see what subscriptions exist currently for NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I am concerned with my NServiceBus solution.

I have a "MessageHub" that publishes some very important messages.  But sometimes it loses track of its subscriptions and just discards the message because it thinks no one is listening.

I have tried turning on "NServiceBus.Integration" to store the subscriptions.  But despite that, I still have issues with bad start up order where it thinks nothing is listening.

Is there a way to debug this process?  Try to figure out why it is getting confused?

I don't even know a way to look at what subscriptions it "thinks" it has...

I went with NServiceBus because it is not supposed to lose data ever.   Now I am losing large chucks.  I know it is a config issue, but it is causing much grief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably happening in your case is that you are using MSMQ for subscription storage. Even though it's possible for subscriptions to endure for a while, using MSMQ to store things long term is always going to be volatile.

For durable subscriptions storage (which survive "forever") you should be using SQL server as your subscription storage.

Note: You can always view your current subscriptions whether you are using sql or msmq to store them. In SQL just look in the subscriptions table and for msmq look in the publisher's subscription queue.

**UPDATE**

Since version 3 I have been using RavenDb which is the default.

Comment: The production profile stores subscription data in a database in version 2.6, and in RavenDB in version 3.0. In both cases, you will be able to see the subscriptions.

Comment: The Publishers Subscription tool had the right queue in there.  But it did not actually show up in the other queue.  (I even tried deleting the queues and remaking them.)  This all went wrong after I ran the runner.exe tool (I ran that because I was having DTC issues.)

Comment: I just need a more solid solution that publish/subscribe can offer.  Since I did not go for a full fix, I am going to mark your answer as "Correct".  I switched up my system to not use publishing.  Now it is direct `Send`s.  Hopefully that will make everything much more reliable.

Comment: NSB pub-sub based solutions are just as "solid" as point-to-point based solutions, provided you use persistent subscription storage and transactional queues. For a better understanding of the NSB subscription model see diagram in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9307852/569662

Answer (score 0):

In my experiance, to get the subscriptions assigned correctly, one should first start the EventHandler projects and then when they are all idle, start the CommandHandlers (Publishers).

You can see what messages are being Subscribed to using Service Bus MQ Manager, it has a dialog listing all "messages" and their subscribers/publishers. A side project of mine, its free and open sourced. 
http://blog.halan.se/page/Service-Bus-MQ-Manager.aspx